# Redshift behaving weirdly / probably driver problem

Tags: 18.04, drivers, apt, ubuntu-mate, redshift

I tried to update my graphics drivers from AMD for my laptop. I am running ubuntu mate (`Linux <hostname> 4.15.0-96-generic #97-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 1 03:25:46 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`) It runs on an amd apu with radeon r7 graphics. Afterwards redshift, a program to change the color temperature of the display during night hours, stopped working correctly. I have uninstalled the drivers and reinstalled the repository ones.

The problem is: seemingly all pure white surfaces don't get the color corrections applied, while all others do. Some weird scrolling behavior in the web browser can also be seen. I confirmed this with a color picker. Most annoyingly window shadows do get this applied and when they move over a white area, it becomes orange in a thick outline.
Unfortunately I can't make a screenshot of the phenomenon as the redshift happens afterwards.

I think the issue is not with redshift but rather with the driver acting up. I have no idea where to start.
I already reinstalled mesa drivers and redshift from repositories.

Here's my apt log.

```
# Installing driver prerequisites (as per instructions for amd drivers)

Start-Date: 2020-04-10  21:09:28
Commandline: apt install vulkan-sdk
Requested-By: paul (1000)
Install: lunarg-vulkan-layers:amd64 (1.2.135.0~rc2-1ubuntu18.04.1.1, automatic), spirv-headers:amd64 (1.5.1+37-1ubuntu18.04.1.1, automatic), shaderc:amd64 (2019.1+28-1ubuntu18.04.1.1, automatic), spirv-cross-dev:amd64 (2020.02.26+22-1ubuntu18.04.1.1, automatic), libvulkan-dev:amd64 (1.2.135.0~rc2-1ubuntu18.04.1.1, automatic), lunarg-vktrace:amd64 (1.2.135.0~rc2-1ubuntu18.04.1.1, automatic), vulkan-headers:amd64 (1.2.135.0~rc2-1ubuntu18.04.1.1, automatic), libminizip1:amd64 (1.1-8build1, automatic), libqt5webenginewidgets5:amd64 (5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2, automatic), glslang-dev:amd64 (8.13.3559+168-1ubuntu18.04.1.1, automatic), libre2-4:amd64 (20180201+dfsg-2, automatic), libqt5webengine-data:amd64 (5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2, automatic), spirv-cross:amd64 (2020.02.26+22-1ubuntu18.04.1.1, automatic), vulkan-tools:amd64 (1.2.135.0~rc2-1ubuntu18.04.1.1, automatic), spirv-tools:amd64 (2020.2-1ubuntu18.04.1.1, automatic), lunarg-vkconfig:amd64 (1.2.135.0~rc2-1ubuntu18.04.1.1, automatic), lunarg-via:amd64 (1.2.135.0~rc2-1ubuntu18.04.1.1, automatic), libqt5webenginecore5:amd64 (5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2, automatic), vulkan-sdk:amd64 (1.2.135.0~rc1-1lunarg18.04.1.1), vulkan-validationlayers:amd64 (1.2.135.0~rc2-1ubuntu18.04.1.1, automatic), glslang-tools:amd64 (8.13.3559+168-1ubuntu18.04.1.1, automatic), vulkan-validationlayers-dev:amd64 (1.2.135.0~rc2-1ubuntu18.04.1.1, automatic)
Upgrade: libvulkan1:amd64 (1.1.70+dfsg1-1ubuntu0.18.04.1, 1.2.135.0~rc2-1ubuntu18.04.1.1), libvulkan1:i386 (1.1.70+dfsg1-1ubuntu0.18.04.1, 1.2.135.0~rc2-1ubuntu18.04.1.1)
End-Date: 2020-04-10  21:09:43

# install amd drivers via install script

Start-Date: 2020-04-10  21:10:56
Commandline: apt install amdgpu amdgpu-lib32
Requested-By: paul (1000)
Install: libgbm1-amdgpu:amd64 (1:18.0.0-673703, automatic), libgbm1-amdgpu:i386 (1:18.0.0-673703, automatic), libglapi-amdgpu-mesa:amd64 (1:18.0.0-673703, automatic), libglapi-amdgpu-mesa:i386 (1:18.0.0-673703, automatic), amdgpu-core:amd64 (18.20-673703, automatic), amdgpu-lib32:amd64 (18.20-673703), libllvm6.0-amdgpu:amd64 (1:6.0-673703, automatic), libllvm6.0-amdgpu:i386 (1:6.0-673703, automatic), libdrm-amdgpu-amdgpu1:amd64 (1:2.4.91-673703, automatic), libdrm-amdgpu-amdgpu1:i386 (1:2.4.91-673703, automatic), amdgpu:amd64 (18.20-673703), libgles1-amdgpu-mesa:amd64 (1:18.0.0-673703, automatic), libgles1-amdgpu-mesa:i386 (1:18.0.0-673703, automatic), mesa-amdgpu-omx-drivers:amd64 (1:18.0.0-673703, automatic), libwayland-amdgpu-client0:amd64 (1.14.0-673703, automatic), libwayland-amdgpu-client0:i386 (1.14.0-673703, automatic), gst-omx-amdgpu:amd64 (1.0.0.1-673703, automatic), libwayland-amdgpu-egl1-mesa:amd64 (1:18.0.0-673703, automatic), libwayland-amdgpu-egl1-mesa:i386 (1:18.0.0-673703, automatic), glamor-amdgpu:amd64 (1.19.0-673703, automatic), libomxil-bellagio0:amd64 (0.9.3-4, automatic), libwayland-amdgpu-server0:amd64 (1.14.0-673703, automatic), libwayland-amdgpu-server0:i386 (1.14.0-673703, automatic), libgles2-amdgpu-mesa:amd64 (1:18.0.0-673703, automatic), libgles2-amdgpu-mesa:i386 (1:18.0.0-673703, automatic), libosmesa6-amdgpu:amd64 (1:18.0.0-673703, automatic), libosmesa6-amdgpu:i386 (1:18.0.0-673703, automatic), libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers:amd64 (1:18.0.0-673703, automatic), libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers:i386 (1:18.0.0-673703, automatic), mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers:amd64 (1:18.0.0-673703, automatic), mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers:i386 (1:18.0.0-673703, automatic), libegl1-amdgpu-mesa:amd64 (1:18.0.0-673703, automatic), libegl1-amdgpu-mesa:i386 (1:18.0.0-673703, automatic), amdgpu-dkms:amd64 (18.20-673703, automatic), mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers:amd64 (1:18.0.0-673703, automatic), mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers:i386 (1:18.0.0-673703, automatic), xserver-xorg-amdgpu-video-amdgpu:amd64 (1:1.4.0-673703, automatic), libomxil-bellagio-bin:amd64 (0.9.3-4, automatic), libxatracker2-amdgpu:amd64 (1:18.0.0-673703, automatic), libxatracker2-amdgpu:i386 (1:18.0.0-673703, automatic), libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri:amd64 (1:18.0.0-673703, automatic), libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri:i386 (1:18.0.0-673703, automatic), ids-amdgpu:amd64 (1.0.0-673703, automatic), libdrm2-amdgpu:amd64 (1:2.4.91-673703, automatic), libdrm2-amdgpu:i386 (1:2.4.91-673703, automatic), libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-glx:amd64 (1:18.0.0-673703, automatic), libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-glx:i386 (1:18.0.0-673703, automatic)
End-Date: 2020-04-10  21:13:29

# rerun install script with opencl option

Start-Date: 2020-04-10  21:13:59
Commandline: apt install amdgpu amdgpu-lib32 clinfo-amdgpu-pro opencl-orca-amdgpu-pro-icd clinfo-amdgpu-pro opencl-amdgpu-pro-icd
Requested-By: paul (1000)
Install: amdgpu-pro-core:amd64 (18.20-673703, automatic), opencl-amdgpu-pro-icd:amd64 (18.20-673703), opencl-orca-amdgpu-pro-icd:amd64 (18.20-673703), libopencl1-amdgpu-pro:amd64 (18.20-673703, automatic), clinfo-amdgpu-pro:amd64 (18.20-673703)
End-Date: 2020-04-10  21:14:07

# rerun install script with vulkan and opencl support

Start-Date: 2020-04-10  21:15:07
Commandline: apt install amdgpu amdgpu-lib32 amdgpu-pro vulkan-amdgpu-pro amdgpu-pro-lib32 vulkan-amdgpu-pro:i386 clinfo-amdgpu-pro opencl-orca-amdgpu-pro-icd clinfo-amdgpu-pro opencl-amdgpu-pro-icd
Requested-By: paul (1000)
Install: libgbm1-amdgpu-pro:i386 (18.20-673703, automatic), libgbm1-amdgpu-pro:amd64 (18.20-673703, automatic), vulkan-amdgpu-pro:i386 (18.20-673703), vulkan-amdgpu-pro:amd64 (18.20-673703), libgles2-amdgpu-pro:i386 (18.20-673703, automatic), libgles2-amdgpu-pro:amd64 (18.20-673703, automatic), libgl1-amdgpu-pro-dri:i386 (18.20-673703, automatic), libgl1-amdgpu-pro-dri:amd64 (18.20-673703, automatic), libgl1-amdgpu-pro-ext:amd64 (18.20-673703, automatic), wsa-amdgpu:i386 (18.20-673703, automatic), wsa-amdgpu:amd64 (18.20-673703, automatic), libgl1-amdgpu-pro-glx:i386 (18.20-673703, automatic), libgl1-amdgpu-pro-glx:amd64 (18.20-673703, automatic), libegl1-amdgpu-pro:i386 (18.20-673703, automatic), libegl1-amdgpu-pro:amd64 (18.20-673703, automatic), amdgpu-pro-lib32:amd64 (18.20-673703), amdgpu-pro:amd64 (18.20-673703), libgl1-amdgpu-pro-appprofiles:amd64 (18.20-673703, automatic), libgbm1-amdgpu-pro-base:amd64 (18.20-673703, automatic)
End-Date: 2020-04-10  21:15:16
```

rebooted here, problems appeared

```
# run uninstall script

Start-Date: 2020-04-10  21:21:58
Commandline: apt purge amdgpu-core
Requested-By: paul (1000)
Purge: amdgpu-pro-core:amd64 (18.20-673703), libgbm1-amdgpu-pro:i386 (18.20-673703), libgbm1-amdgpu-pro:amd64 (18.20-673703), libgbm1-amdgpu:amd64 (1:18.0.0-673703), libgbm1-amdgpu:i386 (1:18.0.0-673703), libglapi-amdgpu-mesa:amd64 (1:18.0.0-673703), libglapi-amdgpu-mesa:i386 (1:18.0.0-673703), amdgpu-core:amd64 (18.20-673703), vulkan-amdgpu-pro:i386 (18.20-673703), vulkan-amdgpu-pro:amd64 (18.20-673703), amdgpu-lib32:amd64 (18.20-673703), libllvm6.0-amdgpu:amd64 (1:6.0-673703), libllvm6.0-amdgpu:i386 (1:6.0-673703), libdrm-amdgpu-amdgpu1:amd64 (1:2.4.91-673703), libdrm-amdgpu-amdgpu1:i386 (1:2.4.91-673703), amdgpu:amd64 (18.20-673703), libgles1-amdgpu-mesa:amd64 (1:18.0.0-673703), libgles1-amdgpu-mesa:i386 (1:18.0.0-673703), mesa-amdgpu-omx-drivers:amd64 (1:18.0.0-673703), libwayland-amdgpu-client0:amd64 (1.14.0-673703), libwayland-amdgpu-client0:i386 (1.14.0-673703), gst-omx-amdgpu:amd64 (1.0.0.1-673703), libgles2-amdgpu-pro:i386 (18.20-673703), libgles2-amdgpu-pro:amd64 (18.20-673703), libgl1-amdgpu-pro-dri:i386 (18.20-673703), libgl1-amdgpu-pro-dri:amd64 (18.20-673703), libgl1-amdgpu-pro-ext:amd64 (18.20-673703), wsa-amdgpu:i386 (18.20-673703), wsa-amdgpu:amd64 (18.20-673703), libgl1-amdgpu-pro-glx:i386 (18.20-673703), libgl1-amdgpu-pro-glx:amd64 (18.20-673703), libwayland-amdgpu-egl1-mesa:amd64 (1:18.0.0-673703), libwayland-amdgpu-egl1-mesa:i386 (1:18.0.0-673703), libegl1-amdgpu-pro:i386 (18.20-673703), libegl1-amdgpu-pro:amd64 (18.20-673703), amdgpu-pro-lib32:amd64 (18.20-673703), glamor-amdgpu:amd64 (1.19.0-673703), opencl-amdgpu-pro-icd:amd64 (18.20-673703), libwayland-amdgpu-server0:amd64 (1.14.0-673703), libwayland-amdgpu-server0:i386 (1.14.0-673703), opencl-orca-amdgpu-pro-icd:amd64 (18.20-673703), libgles2-amdgpu-mesa:amd64 (1:18.0.0-673703), libgles2-amdgpu-mesa:i386 (1:18.0.0-673703), libosmesa6-amdgpu:amd64 (1:18.0.0-673703), libosmesa6-amdgpu:i386 (1:18.0.0-673703), libopencl1-amdgpu-pro:amd64 (18.20-673703), libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers:amd64 (1:18.0.0-673703), libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers:i386 (1:18.0.0-673703), mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers:amd64 (1:18.0.0-673703), mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers:i386 (1:18.0.0-673703), libegl1-amdgpu-mesa:amd64 (1:18.0.0-673703), libegl1-amdgpu-mesa:i386 (1:18.0.0-673703), amdgpu-dkms:amd64 (18.20-673703), mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers:amd64 (1:18.0.0-673703), mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers:i386 (1:18.0.0-673703), amdgpu-pro:amd64 (18.20-673703), xserver-xorg-amdgpu-video-amdgpu:amd64 (1:1.4.0-673703), libgl1-amdgpu-pro-appprofiles:amd64 (18.20-673703), libgbm1-amdgpu-pro-base:amd64 (18.20-673703), libxatracker2-amdgpu:amd64 (1:18.0.0-673703), libxatracker2-amdgpu:i386 (1:18.0.0-673703), libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri:amd64 (1:18.0.0-673703), libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri:i386 (1:18.0.0-673703), ids-amdgpu:amd64 (1.0.0-673703), libdrm2-amdgpu:amd64 (1:2.4.91-673703), libdrm2-amdgpu:i386 (1:2.4.91-673703), clinfo-amdgpu-pro:amd64 (18.20-673703), libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-glx:amd64 (1:18.0.0-673703), libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-glx:i386 (1:18.0.0-673703)
End-Date: 2020-04-10  21:22:24

Start-Date: 2020-04-10  21:28:25
Commandline: apt autoremove
Requested-By: paul (1000)
Remove: libomxil-bellagio0:amd64 (0.9.3-4), libomxil-bellagio-bin:amd64 (0.9.3-4)
End-Date: 2020-04-10  21:28:28
```

Steam started acting up, saying opengl not supported by display or something, started installing opengl

```
Start-Date: 2020-04-10  21:28:57
Commandline: apt install freeglut3-dev
Requested-By: paul (1000)
Install: freeglut3:amd64 (2.8.1-3, automatic), freeglut3-dev:amd64 (2.8.1-3)
End-Date: 2020-04-10  21:28:58

Start-Date: 2020-04-10  21:29:39
Commandline: apt install binutils-gold g++ mesa-common-dev build-essential libglew1.5-dev libglm-dev
Requested-By: paul (1000)
Install: libglew-dev:amd64 (2.0.0-5), libglm-dev:amd64 (0.9.9~a2-2)
End-Date: 2020-04-10  21:29:41

Start-Date: 2020-04-10  21:30:05
Commandline: apt install --reinstall mesa-utils
Requested-By: paul (1000)
Reinstall: mesa-utils:amd64 (8.4.0-1)
End-Date: 2020-04-10  21:30:07

Start-Date: 2020-04-10  21:37:05
Commandline: apt remove vulkan-sdk
Requested-By: paul (1000)
Remove: vulkan-sdk:amd64 (1.2.135.0~rc1-1lunarg18.04.1.1)
End-Date: 2020-04-10  21:37:07

Start-Date: 2020-04-10  21:37:21
Commandline: apt autoremove
Requested-By: paul (1000)
Remove: lunarg-vulkan-layers:amd64 (1.2.135.0~rc2-1ubuntu18.04.1.1), spirv-headers:amd64 (1.5.1+37-1ubuntu18.04.1.1), shaderc:amd64 (2019.1+28-1ubuntu18.04.1.1), spirv-cross-dev:amd64 (2020.02.26+22-1ubuntu18.04.1.1), libvulkan-dev:amd64 (1.2.135.0~rc2-1ubuntu18.04.1.1), lunarg-vktrace:amd64 (1.2.135.0~rc2-1ubuntu18.04.1.1), vulkan-headers:amd64 (1.2.135.0~rc2-1ubuntu18.04.1.1), libminizip1:amd64 (1.1-8build1), libqt5webenginewidgets5:amd64 (5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2), glslang-dev:amd64 (8.13.3559+168-1ubuntu18.04.1.1), libre2-4:amd64 (20180201+dfsg-2), libqt5webengine-data:amd64 (5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2), spirv-cross:amd64 (2020.02.26+22-1ubuntu18.04.1.1), vulkan-tools:amd64 (1.2.135.0~rc2-1ubuntu18.04.1.1), spirv-tools:amd64 (2020.2-1ubuntu18.04.1.1), lunarg-vkconfig:amd64 (1.2.135.0~rc2-1ubuntu18.04.1.1), lunarg-via:amd64 (1.2.135.0~rc2-1ubuntu18.04.1.1), libqt5webenginecore5:amd64 (5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2), vulkan-validationlayers:amd64 (1.2.135.0~rc2-1ubuntu18.04.1.1), glslang-tools:amd64 (8.13.3559+168-1ubuntu18.04.1.1), vulkan-validationlayers-dev:amd64 (1.2.135.0~rc2-1ubuntu18.04.1.1)
End-Date: 2020-04-10  21:37:24

Start-Date: 2020-04-10  21:38:29
Commandline: apt install --reinstall mesa-utils
Requested-By: paul (1000)
Reinstall: mesa-utils:amd64 (8.4.0-1)
End-Date: 2020-04-10  21:38:31

Start-Date: 2020-04-10  21:55:48
Commandline: apt install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-dri
Reinstall: libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 (19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3), libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 (19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3)
End-Date: 2020-04-10  21:55:51

Start-Date: 2020-04-10  22:17:33
Commandline: apt remove mesa-vulkan-drivers
Remove: mesa-vulkan-drivers:amd64 (19.3.3~kisak2~b)
End-Date: 2020-04-10  22:17:33

Start-Date: 2020-04-10  22:17:56
Commandline: apt install mesa-vulkan-drivers
Install: mesa-vulkan-drivers:amd64 (19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3)
Remove: mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386 (19.3.3~kisak2~b)
End-Date: 2020-04-10  22:17:57

Start-Date: 2020-04-10  22:18:57
Commandline: apt remove libxatracker2
Remove: libxatracker2:amd64 (19.3.3~kisak2~b), xserver-xorg-video-vmware:amd64 (1:13.2.1-1build1), xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 (1:7.7+19ubuntu7.1)
End-Date: 2020-04-10  22:18:58

Start-Date: 2020-04-10  22:19:09
Commandline: apt autoremove
Remove: libvulkan1:i386 (1.2.135.0~rc2-1ubuntu18.04.1.1), libxcb-randr0:i386 (1.13-2~ubuntu18.04)
End-Date: 2020-04-10  22:19:10

Start-Date: 2020-04-10  22:19:37
Commandline: apt install xserver-xorg-video-all
Install: libxatracker2:amd64 (19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3, automatic), xserver-xorg-video-vmware:amd64 (1:13.2.1-1build1, automatic), xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 (1:7.7+19ubuntu7.1)
End-Date: 2020-04-10  22:19:38
```

At this point local packages were installed and I couldn't get apt to install the repository versions. So I ran

```bsh
dpkg -r --force-depends libdrm-common libegl-mesa0 libegl1-mesa libgbm1 libgl1-mesa-glx libglapi-mesa libglx-mesa0 libllvm9 libvulkan1 libwayland-egl1-mesa
apt --fix-broken install
```

```
Start-Date: 2020-04-10  22:34:00
Commandline: apt --fix-broken install
Install: libvulkan1:amd64 (1.1.70+dfsg1-1ubuntu0.18.04.1, automatic), libllvm9:amd64 (1:9-2~ubuntu18.04.2, automatic), libllvm9:i386 (1:9-2~ubuntu18.04.2, automatic), libegl-mesa0:amd64 (19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3, automatic), libglapi-mesa:amd64 (19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3, automatic), libglapi-mesa:i386 (19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3, automatic), libgbm1:amd64 (19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3, automatic), libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 (19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3, automatic), libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 (19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3, automatic), libglx-mesa0:amd64 (19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3, automatic), libglx-mesa0:i386 (19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3, automatic), libdrm-common:amd64 (2.4.99-1ubuntu1~18.04.2, automatic)
End-Date: 2020-04-10  22:34:07

Start-Date: 2020-04-10  22:35:35
Commandline: apt install libegl1-mesa
Install: libegl1-mesa:amd64 (19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3)
End-Date: 2020-04-10  22:35:36

Start-Date: 2020-04-10  22:38:32
Commandline: apt install --reinstall libdrm-amdgpu1
Reinstall: libdrm-amdgpu1:amd64 (2.4.99-1ubuntu1~18.04.2), libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 (2.4.99-1ubuntu1~18.04.2)
End-Date: 2020-04-10  22:38:33
```

Comment: Ubuntu 19.04 is EOL or *end-of-life* (http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/01/23/ubuntu-19-04-disco-dingo-end-of-life-reached-on-january-23-2020/) thus off-topic on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) unless your question is specific to help moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Use a LTS or *long-term-support* release if you don't like *release-upgrading* every 6-9 months.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: Ensure you don't have multiple programs like `redshift` running, as they tend to interfere with each other (default ubuntu setups come with programs other than redshift, so if you've introduced other GNOME packages you may have brought another in), however you've tagged an EOL & thus off-topic release so I didn't explore further (I don't recall when night light became standard for Ubuntu..)

Comment: Check your details; you mentioned a 18.04 kernel (4.15) but then list your release as 19.04?

Comment: @guiverc I misstyped. I'm running 18.04.4 LTS

Comment: @guiverc I'm pretty sure I am only running redshift. I certainly didn't start anything else manually or am aware of having installed anything else. not running multiple instances either. I have heard about this nightlight thing, too and tried to install that after noticing the problem with redshift. however I couldn't find it in the mate repositories, and certainly not on my system.